# How to check if customer is logged in or not?

Tags: magento2, customer, login, customer-account, customer-session

How to **find if a customer is logged in or not in Magento 2.**

If the customer is logged in then how to get customer data from a session?

Comment: none of the solution mentioned here worked for me. @Rakesh : could you share how it worked for you?

Comment: Keep in mind that if you ever need to check logged in status from within a Magento JS module (`text/x-magento-init`), then you can save some overhead by avoiding ObjectManager instantiation and passing the status to the module's config object, and instead query for the login link from within the JS module, e.g.: `var isLoggedIn = $('.authorization-link > a').attr('href').indexOf('/login')<0;`

Comment: @Rakesh, Coul you please check these, https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/185994/add-image-attribute-to-registration-page-magento-2 ,, https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/186036/sign-up-with-avatar-rest-api-validation-error-magento-2

Comment: What the below line is doing ?                                                                              
                                                 var isLoggedIn = $('.authorization-link > a').attr('href').indexOf('/login')<0;

Comment: Check link, https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/how-to-check-if-customer-is-logged-in-or-not-in-magento-2

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Following code you can check customer login or not anywhere

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
   // customer login action
}
```

From controller

```
$customerSession = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
   // customer login action
}
```

Comment: Of course, it is the most evident solution, and I employed it first time, but then I noticed that it does not work correctly when the customer session is not initialized yet, so I have found a less evident but more sustainable solution.

Comment: One should not use objectmanager directly.  Simply inject the ObjectFactory  generated code for the session model.

Comment: please don't copy other answers in your answer.

Comment: I don't copy answer from other. I just updated this for current  version.

Comment: this is the "wrong" way, the answer from Raphael at Digital Pianism is the rigth one

Comment: @Sohel, Could you please check these, https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/185994/add-image-attribute-to-registration-page-magento-2 ,, https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/186036/sign-up-with-avatar-rest-api-validation-error-magento-2

Comment: It didn't work for me on 2.2.2!

Comment: If you have enabled full page cache and you call this in block/template, it doesn't work as customer session will always return empty. Use http context to check it instead.

Comment: Not working in 2.3

Comment: Not working for me also.

Answer (score 113):

Important reminder: **[One should never call the Object Manager directly](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/117098/magento-2-to-use-or-not-to-use-the-objectmanager-directly)**

Thus here's **how to do it the clean way**

### In any class except templates

You first need to inject the following class in your constructor: `/Magento/Customer/Model/Session` :

```
protected $_customerSession;    // don't name this `$_session` since it is already used in \Magento\Customer\Model\Session and your override would cause problems

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $session,
    ...
) {
    ...
    $this->_customerSession = $session;
    ...
}
```

Then in your class you can call the following:

```
if ($this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
    // Customer is logged in 
} else {
    // Customer is not logged in
}
```

### In a template

It requires a bit more work in a template as you will have to setup a preference for the block that renders the template to do that the clean way:

```
<preference for="Block\That\Renders\The\Template"
            type="Vendor\Module\Block\Your\Custom\Block" />
```

Then in your custom block contrusctor you need to following the same dependency injection as for any class (explained above).

The **extra step here is to create a public method that can be used in your template to check whether a customer is logged in or not**

```
public function isCustomerLoggedIn()
{
    return $this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn();
}
```

Then in your template you can call:

```
if ($block->isCustomerLoggedIn()) {
    // Customer is logged in
} else {
    // Customer is not logged in
}
```

### Alternative if the customer session is not initialized yet

There's another way of doing it which implies using `Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context` instead of `Magento/Customer/Model/Session`

Then you can call `$this->_context->getValue(\Magento\Customer\Model\Context::CONTEXT_AUTH)` instead of `$this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn()` to check whether the customer is logged in or not.

**However this method may give you different results**, I suggest you read this great answer for more information: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/92133/2380

Comment: Where should be placed the `<preference ... />` tag within a custom theme? What are exactly `Block\That\Renders\The\Template` and `Vendor\Module\Block\Your\Custom\Block`?

Comment: @Andrea well it depends and it's different for each case. That's why I used generic class path names in my answer

Comment: I have a custom block defined as `class Html extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template` where I can inject the session object in the constructor. I use this block within my custom theme in this way (from layout xml files): `<block class="Vendor\ThemeName\Block\Html" template="Vendor_ModuleName::html/my-custom-template.phtml"/>`. I would like to check the logged user within the template file `my-custom-template.phtml`. How should I use the `<preference .../> tag?

Comment: Doesn't work for me the ->isLoggedin() method. I don't know why but it never returns that customer is logged in, and it actually is! It is logged in (I am logged in).

Comment: @VladimirDespotovic did you test the alternative method ?

Comment: I had to call the variable `$_customerSession` instead of `$_session`. It seems that when extending `Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template` the variable `$_session` is already used for `\Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface` in `AbstractBlock`. So first I got the error `Invalid method Magento\Framework\Session\Generic\Interceptor::isLoggedIn(Array` (...)

Comment: $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$context = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context');
$isLoggedIn = $context->getValue(\Magento\Customer\Model\Context::CONTEXT_AUTH);
if ($isLoggedIn):
   
    $class = "action add add-your-review";

else:
    $class = "open-login-poup";

endif;

Comment: I am using above method, shall I get customer name or id using the above one

Comment: Very important comments here on protected $_session var `// don't name this `$_session` since it is already used in \Magento\Customer\Model\Session and your override would cause problems` I had an error `Invalid method Magento Framework Session Generic Interceptor isLoggedIn Array` After renaming it works!

Comment: You don't need the `preference` part at all, why is it in the answer?

Answer (score 44):

It is possible via `Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context` or via `Magento\Customer\Model\Session`. However, the result may be different:

- HTTP context is initialized earlier than the customer session (but it does not matter since both are initialized in action controllers)
- When the `PageCache` module is on (probably always on production), keep in mind that as soon as layout generation started, the customer session will be cleared by `\Magento\PageCache\Model\Layout\DepersonalizePlugin::afterGenerateXml` on all cacheable pages. It means that if you now check if the customer is logged in via the HTTP context, it will still say 'yes, but customer data will not be available in customer sessions anymore. So double-check is necessary before trying to access data in customer sessions. This can easily happen in the block, while is unlikely in action controller since you are not expected to generate layout manually there, it will be generated after-action controller returns an instance of `ResultInterface`

To eliminate any risk of described inconsistencies when PageCache is on, consider using customer session if it is already initialized (true for action controllers). Else use the HTTP context.

Comment: great hint for PageCache enabled, thx

Comment: @Alex I am using below code
$customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context');
    $isLoggedIn = $customerSession->getValue(\Magento\Customer\Model\Context::CONTEXT_AUTH);
But due to cache enable It showing Sign In option instead of Sign Out to logged in customer. How should I fix this?

Comment: This bit us in the arse, thank you. Your answer needs more attention :-) The cache being enabled in production makes session difficult. Put cachable = false in the XML file of the route if you're writing custom magento plugins.

Comment: why do you have to put cachable = false?

Answer (score 19):

None of these solutions worked for me.  Some pages would appear to be logged in but others would not.  It seems this is the bug:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/3294

I ended up creating a helper which I could call in my templates:

```
<?php
namespace MyVendor\MyModule\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;

/**
 * Created by Carl Owens (carl@partfire.co.uk)
 * Company: PartFire Ltd (www.partfire.co.uk)
 **/
class Data extends AbstractHelper
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context
     */
    private $httpContext;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->httpContext = $httpContext;
    }

    public function isLoggedIn()
    {
        $isLoggedIn = $this->httpContext->getValue(\Magento\Customer\Model\Context::CONTEXT_AUTH);
        return $isLoggedIn;
    }
}
```

Then I could use the helper in my templates like so:

```
<?php
$helper = $this->helper('MyVendor\MyModule\Helper\Data');

if ($helper->isLoggedIn()) {
    //show something
}
```

Comment: That's true, the only code that worked on me is yours. Thank you!

Comment: How can I call `->getCustomer()->getName()` using the context, because If I use the Session is not working for all pages.

Comment: if full page cache is enabled this is the right answer. You can check customersession first and if that returns false you can do this

Answer (score 17):

```
/** @var \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager $om */
$om = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
/** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $context */
$context = $om->get('Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context');
/** @var bool $isLoggedIn */
$isLoggedIn = $context->getValue(\Magento\Customer\Model\Context::CONTEXT_AUTH);
```

Comment: so how get custommer is login @Mage2.PRO ?

Comment: You should never use ObjectManager directly

Comment: Yes, agreed. Objectmanager is not the way to go.  Inject the CustomerFactory in the class constructor.

Comment: The above solution doesnt work for me

Comment: @lpsita Let me know if you have this issue? I just fixed it :)

Comment: This Works for me on 2.2.2

Comment: It does not work when cache is on

Answer (score 14):

None of the solutions here worked for me reliably in Magento v2.1 with Full Page Cache and Varnish enabled in Production mode. I finally found a solution that worked 100% of the time with all caching enabled after getting the idea from `vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/header.phtml`. Here is my solution, which shows a "Sign In" link when the user is logged out and a "Sign Out" link when the user is logged in:

```
<li data-bind="scope: 'customer'">
  <!-- ko if: customer().firstname  -->
  <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('customer/account/logout'); ?>" style="display:none;" data-bind="style: {display:'inline'}"><?php echo __('Sign Out') ?></a>
  <!-- /ko -->
  <!-- ko ifnot: customer().firstname  -->
  <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('customer/account/login'); ?>" style="display:none;" data-bind="style: {display:'inline'}"><?php echo __('Sign In') ?></a>
  <!-- /ko -->
  <script type="text/x-magento-init">
  {
    "*": {
      "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
        "components": {
          "customer": {
            "component": "Magento_Customer/js/view/customer"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  </script>
</li>
```

UPDATE: Since v2.1.5 this solution is no longer reliable. See [issue 9156](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/9156) for a solution.

Comment: It is a good solution. Though you can use cachable="false" in layout file.

Comment: I have `cachable="false"` in layout XML for this block, but varnish is still caching it apparently. Not sure if this is a bug or not, but Knockout is a good way to circumvent this. The only downside is that there is a little delay before the Sign In/Out link shows up because of KO binding.

Answer (score 13):

To get user logged in at template, you can simply call helper in just one single line :

```
<?php $_loggedin = $this->helper('Magento\Checkout\Helper\Cart')->getCart()->getCustomerSession()->isLoggedIn(); ?>

<?php if( $_loggedin ) : ?>

     <div><!-- add your code --></div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Nice solution without using objectmanager.

Comment: This did not work in v2.1.5 with FPC and Varnish enabled in production mode.

Comment: How would you flip this around to check if the customer is NOT logged in?

Answer (score 12):

Another answer:

```
<?php $_loggedin = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Customer\Block\Account\AuthorizationLink')->isLoggedIn() ?>
 <?php if( $_loggedin ) : ?>
   // your code
 <?php endif; ?>
```

What do you think?

Comment: its worked for me on phtml page

Answer (score 11):

Fetching the logged status from Session model will not work in case you want to use it after enabling Magento default FPC cache, in that case, you should use SessionFactory instead.

Session is not initiated if FPC caching is enabled, details: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/3294#issuecomment-328464943

To solve this you have to use `SessionFactory`, for example:

```
/**
* @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Session
*/
protected $_customerSessionFactory;

public function __construct(
    ....
    \Magento\Customer\Model\SessionFactory $customerSessionFactory
    ....
) 
{
    ....
    $this->_customerSessionFactory = $customerSessionFactory;
    ....
}

public function getCustomerId(){
  $customer = $this->_customerSessionFactory->create();
  echo $customer->getCustomer()->getId();
}
```

Comment: This worked for me, also, if you want to check if customer has logged in, by your solution, use `$customer->isLoggedIn()`

Comment: Finally. Something that works on Magento 2.4 with FPC enabled. Thank you!

Comment: this is work on Magento 2.4, Thanks

Answer (score 7):

There are a lot of answers out there that go something like this...

GET OBJECT MANAGER
LOAD UP CLASS MODEL
DO STUFF

This is the WRONG methodology to use in Magento2.0. In 2.0, the auto generated object factories are the way to go.  You can inject them into your constructor in *almost* any class and use them.  Example:

```
public function __construct(
            Context $context,
            CollectionFactory $cmspageCollectionFactory,
            array $data = [],
            CustomerFactory $customerFactory,
            SessionFactory $sessionFactory)
        {
            parent::__construct($context, $data);
            $this->_cmspageCollectionFactory = $cmspageCollectionFactory;
            $this->customerFactory = $customerFactory;
            $this->sessionFactory = $sessionFactory;
        }

        /**
         * @return \Stti\Healthday\Model\ResourceModel\Cmspage\Collection
         */
        public function getCmspages()
        {
            // First check to see if someone is currently logged in.
            $customerSession = $this->sessionFactory->create();
            if ($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
                // customer is logged in;
                //$customer = $this->customerFactory->create()->get
            }
```

Comment: If you get an error for the factories, then use the full path, e.g. `\Magento\Customer\Model\SessionFactory $sessionFactory`.

Comment: Correct. I usually declare them at the top, just so my methods don't look like a huge mess :)

Answer (score 6):

I have get the best solution. It is based on **authentication of customer**. Some of the case **customer session** was not working, But every time my solution will work. Lets take a look.

```
<?php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Block\Account\AuthorizationLink');
if ($customerSession->isLoggedIn() == true) {
//your code.
} ?>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Great job! Thanks you.

Answer (score 5):

Hello got answer here :

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerSession = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');

if ($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
    $customerSession->getCustomerId();  // get Customer Id
    $customerSession->getCustomerGroupId();
    $customerSession->getCustomer();
    $customerSession->getCustomerData();

    echo $customerSessionget->getCustomer()->getName();  // get  Full Name
    echo $customerSessionget->getCustomer()->getEmail(); // get Email
}
```

[Source](http://www.sharad-patel.com/magento2-get-current-customer-emailname-and-customer-data/).

```
$customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
```

Replaced get with create now works fine:

```
$customerSession = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
```

Comment: You should never use `ObjectManager` directly

Comment: This works only if cache is disable not in enabled-cache.

Comment: @Jai, this work for me in development and production as well. Please can you send me the steps to reproduce the issue ?

Comment: I have to check if user is logged in or not. But below code works only in disabled cache
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerSession = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');

if ($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) { //CODE}

Comment: In enable cached: It works only on custom-dashboard pages not in home-page and other pages of site. My question: https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/177964/29175

Comment: I make it working

Comment: perfect answer!!! +1 made my day :)

Answer (score 5):

This is also one of the solution "Check whether the Customer is Logged in or not in Magento2"

Try below code:

```
 $om = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
 $context = $om->get('Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context');
 $isLoggedIn = $context->getValue(\Magento\Customer\Model\Context::CONTEXT_AUTH);
 if($isLoggedIn){
      echo "Yes Customer loggedin";
      echo "<pre>";print_r($context->getData()); 
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Try below code:

```
<?php
namespace YourCompany\ModuleName\Helper;

class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
    ) {
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

public function isLoggedIn() // You can use this fucntion in any phtml file
    {
        return $this->customerSession->isLoggedIn();
    }
}
```

For using above code in phtml file you can call isLoggedIn() function as:

```
<?php $helper = $this->helper('YourCompany\ModuleName\Helper\Data'); ?>
<?php if($helper->isLoggedIn()) : ?>
    logged in
<?php else : ?>
    not logged in
<?php endif; ?>
```

Hope this help thanks.

Comment: hi @Shubdham, its not working..

Comment: this is a neat solution. thanks

Comment: Yeah thanks hope it helps you.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check customer logged in or not then use this code in phtml files,

```
$om = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$appContext = $om->get('Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context');
$isLoggedIn = $appContext->getValue(\Magento\Customer\Model\Context::CONTEXT_AUTH);
if($isLoggedIn) {
    /** LOGGED IN CUSTOMER, this should work in template   **/
}
```

Comment: You should never use `ObjectManager` directly and you should never use this type of code in a template. You should create functionalities in your block class to manage this.

Comment: Once you know how to do it correctly, you wonder how you ever manager to do it the other way at all!

Answer (score 1):

#### Current worked solution (IMHO)

```
<?php

namespace My\Module\Helper\Data;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface
 */
protected $objectManager;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\SessionFactory
 */
protected $customerSession;

/**
 * Class Data
 */
class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager
     */
    public function __construct(
         \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager
    )
    {
        $this->objectManager   = $objectManager;
        $this->customerSession = $this->objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\SessionFactory')->create();
    }

    /**
     * @return \Magento\Customer\Model\SessionFactory
     */
    public function getCustomerSession()
    {
       return $this->customerSession;     
    }

    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isCustomerLoggedIn()
    {
        return ($this->getCustomerSession()->isLoggedIn()) ? true : false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');

if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest this solution which uses multiple fallbacks

```
...

private $appContext;
private $session;

public function __construct(
   \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $appContext,
   \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $session
   ...
) {
    ...

    $this->appContext = $appContext;
    $this->session = $session;

    ...
}

public function isLoggedIn()
{
    if (empty($this->session)) { return false; }
    if ($this->session->isLoggedIn()) { return true; }
    return $this->appContext->getValue(\Magento\Customer\Model\Context::CONTEXT_AUTH);
}

...
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare `\Magento\Customer\Model\SessionFactory` in construct of your class.

```
protected $customerSession;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Customer\Model\SessionFactory $customerSession
) {
    $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
}

public function isLoggedIn() // You can use this function in phtml file
{
    return $this->customerSession->create()->isLoggedIn();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just add this script in your phtml file if you want to check using JS and change code in your `if else`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(['jquery'], function($){
        jQuery(document).ready( function() {
            var isLoggedIn = jQuery('.authorization-link > a').attr('href').indexOf('/login')<0;
            
            if(isLoggedIn){
                
            }else{
                
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 2, you can get customer data from a session if the customer is logged in by injecting the Magento\Customer\Model\Session class in your class constructor and then using the getCustomerData() method to retrieve the customer data.

Here's an example code snippet:

```
<?php
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session as CustomerSession;

class MyCustomClass
{
    protected $customerSession;

    public function __construct(CustomerSession $customerSession)
    {
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
    }

    public function getCustomerData()
    {
        if ($this->customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
            $customerData = $this->customerSession->getCustomerData();
            // $customerData will contain an array of customer data
            // Example:
            $customerId = $customerData['customer_id'];
            $customerEmail = $customerData['email'];
            $customerFirstname = $customerData['firstname'];
            $customerLastname = $customerData['lastname'];
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

In this example, we first check if the customer is logged in using the isLoggedIn() method. If the customer is logged in, we use the getCustomerData() method to retrieve an array of customer data, which includes the customer's ID, email, firstname, lastname, and other information.

You can then use this customer data as needed in your class.

Thanks !!

Answer (score -1):

I tried many ways found on google but none of the solution works. SO I checked the core functionality and created a php file to check a customer is logged in or not without using the Object Manager.

```
            /**
         * Customer session
         * Module created by Web Technology Codes
         * Developed by Vinay Sikarwar
         * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context
         */
        protected $session;

        /**
         * Registration constructor.
         * @param Context $context
         * @param array $data
         */
        public function __construct(
            Context $context,
                    \Magento\Framework\Session\Generic $session,
            array $data
        )
        {
                    $this->_session = $session;
                    parent::__construct($context, $data);
        }

            /**
         * Checking customer login status
         *
         * @api
         * @return bool
         */
        public function isCustomerLoggedIn()
        {
            return (bool)$this->getCustomerId()
                && $this->checkCustomerId($this->getId())
                && !$this->getIsCustomerEmulated();
        }
    }
```

For more info check it here http://blog.webtechnologycodes.com/customer-loggedin-check-magento2