# Get Customer in product view?

Tags: magento2, customer, product-view

I want to get `customer_id, name and email` of logged in customer in product view. How to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if customer is logged in or not in magento 2?](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91897/how-to-check-if-customer-is-logged-in-or-not-in-magento-2)

Answer (score 2):

You can get it directly from customer session:

> ```
>   $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
>     $customerSession = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
>
>
> if ($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
>     $customerSession->getCustomerId();
>     $customerSession->getCustomerGroupId();
>     $customerSession->getCustomer();
>     $customerSession->getCustomerData();
>     $customerSession->getCustomer()->getEmail();
> }
> ```

Comment: You should never use `\Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()`, instead inject `Magento\Customer\Model\Session` as a dependency to the construct.

Comment: have you check this: http://foggyline.net/magento-2-get-current-logged-in-customer/