# Magento 2 - CurrentCustomer or Session?

Tags: magento2, best-practice, dependency-injection, customer-session

Which class I should inject to get the current customer? What are their differences?

1. `\Magento\Customer\Helper\Session\CurrentCustomer`
2. `\Magento\Customer\Model\Session`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, you can use either of them.

Basically `\Magento\Customer\Helper\Session\CurrentCustomer` uses `\Magento\Customer\Model\Session`.

The benefit of u**sing the helper class is that it provides extra helper methods to get the current customer data** such as:

- `getCustomer` : to load the current customer
- `getCustomerId` : to get the current customer id

The benefit of **using the model class is that you modify the customer data** with:

- `setCustomerData`
- `setCustomer`
- `setCustomerId`
- `setCustomerGroupId`
- `setCustomerAsLoggedIn`

Also **you can do extra stuff that the helper won't let you do**:

- check if the customer is logged in: `isLoggedIn()`
- login with `login()`
- logout with `logout()`

So I guess it depends on your needs:

- if you only need to get customer data you can use `\Magento\Customer\Helper\Session\CurrentCustomer`
- if you need to modify the current customer or interact with it, I suggest you use `\Magento\Customer\Model\Session`

Comment: Thanks for help and nice your answer. How to get current customer in magento 2?

Comment: @PayalPatel here's an answer for you: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92818/get-customer-in-product-view NB: please try to avoid using the object manager directly and inject the class in your constructor directly instead