# After logging in, the user name is not displaying in header section

Tags: magento2, customer, login, header, user

After logging in, the user name is not displaying between 'Wilkommen' and 'Anmelden' .

1. Which files are responsible for rendering out this part of the header ?
2. How to get the user name of the currently logged in user ?

[image]

Comment: You can check if the data is correctly retrieve on the localStorage or by ajax call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Which files are responsible for rendreing out this part of the header
>   ?

/vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/header.phtml

```
<span data-bind="text: customer().fullname ? $t('Welcome, %1!').replace('%1', customer().fullname) : '<?=$block->escapeHtml($welcomeMessage) ?>'"></span>
```

If you have third party theme, the file path can be
app/design/frontend/Vendorname/theme762/Magento_Theme/templates/html/header.phtml

> How to get the username of the currently logged in user ?

Refer the [answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91897/how-to-check-if-customer-is-logged-in-or-not-in-magento-2)

Answer (score 4):

For customer name you need to check 
`vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/header.phtml`

code : `<span data-bind="text: new String('<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Welcome, %1!', '%1'));?>').replace('%1', customer().firstname)">
            </span>`

Data is being fetched by knockout js using :

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
                "components": {
                    "customer": {
                        "component": "Magento_Customer/js/view/customer"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    </script>
```