# Magento 2 Class Inject in Constructor

Tags: magento-2.1, module, dependency-injection

I am trying to create a simple module based on this answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/125519/45358

I just need a function to check if customer is logged or not in a custom theme header.phtml. I am new to Magento 2 and I can't understand how this works. I tried by following some tutorials but I am getting a lot of errors, like class not found and many more. I just need a complete example and then I will understand how actually work.

Here all files in my module

app/code/George/Core

registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
  \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
  'George_Core',
  __DIR__
 );
```

Block/Userlogin/Login

```
<?php
namespace George\Core\Block\Userlogin;

class Login extends Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    public function isCustomerLoggedIn()
{
   return $this->_session->isLoggedIn();
  }

}
```

Model/Index/Index.php

```
<?php
namespace George\Core\Model\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
   protected $_session;

public function __construct(
\Magento\Customer\Model\Session $session,

) {
$this->_session = $session; 
  }

}
```

etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
<module name="George_Core" setup_version="0.0.1"/>
</config>
```

Also I found that need to add somewhere a preference, I understand that preference should be inside /etc/di.xml but how the actual di.xml file should look?

```
 <preference for="Block\That\Renders\The\Template"
        type="Vendor\Module\Block\Your\Custom\Block" />
```

Also in my case I can't understand which is Block\That\Renders\The\Template and Vendor\Module\Block\Your\Custom\Block

Now how can I call this inside custom theme header.phtml template, because if I try that, website stops loading.

```
if ($block->isCustomerLoggedIn()) {
// Customer is logged in
} else {
// Customer is not logged in
}
```

If someone can provide me a simple complete example will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Your di.xml should look like this ;

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
 <preference for="Block\That\Renders\The\Template"
        type="Vendor\Module\Block\Your\Custom\Block" />
</config>
```

Also `Block\That\Renders\The\Template` refers to the path of the block that renders the module.
You can know the path of the block that renders the module by its corresponding xml. Lets take example of store_switcher block ,since it is located in all pages its xml is default.xml located in `app/design/frontend/Magento/luma/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml` for luma  theme .

Its reference container looks like ..

```
<referenceContainer name="footer">
     <block class="Magento\Store\Block\Switcher" name="store_switcher" as="store_switcher" after="footer_links" template="switch/stores.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
```

So its corresponding phtml is `switch/stores.phtml`   and block that renders it is `Magento\Store\Block\Switcher`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but how can I call module on my custom theme?

Comment: You will have to make the function you're calling i.e isCustomerLoggedIn() in your block and call it in your phtml using $block->isCustomerLoggedIn() .

Comment: I am getting an error `Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid method ....::isCustomerLoggedIn`

Comment: Try to var_dump ($this->_session);exit; to check if it is even available in your block . If no you have to inject instance of  Magento\Customer\Model\Session .

Comment: If i place that layout is going broken, everything inside <head></head> not loading

Comment: Make a __construct function in your block and inject the instance of Magento\Customer\Model\Session like you would in a controller and then use that session variable to call isLoggedin() method in your block's method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56550/discussion-between-george-george-and-neo).