# How to get current customer group id in magento2

Tags: magento2, frontend, customer-group

I want to get current customer **group id** in **phtml** file. When I am not logged in still it is return general type **customer group**. How can get proper output?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession` using this class you will get the current customer group id

```
protected $_customerSession;

public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
    ) {
        $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
    }

public function getGroupId(){
 if($this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn()):
        echo $customerGroup=$this->_customerSession->getCustomer()->getGroupId();
    endif;
}
```

**NOTE: You only get customer id if the customer logged in**

Answer (score 11):

By default, Magento will clear the customer session: `\Magento\PageCache\Model\Layout\DepersonalizePlugin::afterGenerateXml`.

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/92133/33057

Take a look:

vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/Context.php

```
/**
 * Customer group cache context
 */
const CONTEXT_GROUP = 'customer_group';
/**
 * Customer authorization cache context
 */
const CONTEXT_AUTH = 'customer_logged_in';
```

We can check the logged in customer and customer group:

```
 /**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext
 */
$isLogged = $this->httpContext->getValue(Context::CONTEXT_AUTH);
$customerGroupId = $this->httpContext->getValue(Context::CONTEXT_GROUP);
```

Put these code lines in your block.

There is another good explanation here:

https://sohel.dev/how-to-get-customer-id-from-block-when-full-page-cache-enable-in-magento-2/

Comment: Here is the new url: https://sohel.dev/how-to-get-customer-id-from-block-when-full-page-cache-enable-in-magento-2/

Answer (score 8):

you can get group Id by following code

```
protected $_customerSession;

public function __construct(
        ....    
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        ....
    ) {


        $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;

    }

public function getGroupId(){
 if($this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn()):
        echo $customerGroup=$this->_customerSession->getCustomer()->getGroupId();
    endif;

}
```

Comment: But it is return 1 (Id of General Customer Group)when I am not logged in.

Comment: @RohanHapani added the code kindly check and feedback..

Comment: @RohanHapani i tested this code it is not showing groupid for not log in user did you  `if($this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn()):` isLoggedIn check?

Answer (score 3):

Try this to get the current customer group Id and name for both logged and not logged-in customers.

```
protected $_customerSession;

protected $_customerGroupCollection;

public function __construct(
    ....    
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Group $customerGroupCollection,
    ....
) {


    $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
    $this->_customerGroupCollection = $customerGroupCollection;

}

public function getCustomerGroup()
{
        echo $currentGroupId = $this->_customerSession->getCustomer()->getGroupId(); //Get current customer group ID
        $collection = $this->_customerGroupCollection->load($currentGroupId); 
        echo $collection->getCustomerGroupCode();//Get current customer group name
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using \Magento\Customer\Model\Session may fail if you use caching.

You should better use :

```php
private $sessionProxy;
       
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session\Proxy $sessionProxy
) {
    $this->sessionProxy= $sessionProxy;
}
     
// may return groupId or \Magento\Customer\Model\GroupManagement::NOT_LOGGED_IN_ID  
public function getGroupId(){
   $this->sessionProxy->getCustomer()->getGroupId();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also get it from the session

```
$group_id=$_SESSION['customer_base']['customer_group_id'];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
protected $_customerSession;

public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
    ) {
        $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
    }

public function getGroupId(){
 if($this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn()):
        echo $customerGroup=$this->_customerSession->getCustomer()->getGroupId();
    endif;
}
```

This May be useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the easiest way to get this from any template file, as stated in question, would be using this helper https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/app/code/Magento/Customer/Helper/Session/CurrentCustomer.php

Method `getCustomer()` will run `getDepersonalizedCustomer()`  and set customer group ID in customer object, even in a cached page context

```
/**
 * Returns current customer according to session and context
 *
 * @return \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface
 */
public function getCustomer()
{
    if ($this->moduleManager->isEnabled('Magento_PageCache')
        && !$this->request->isAjax()
        && $this->view->isLayoutLoaded()
        && $this->layout->isCacheable()
    ) {
        return $this->getDepersonalizedCustomer();
    } else {
        return $this->getCustomerFromService();
    }
}

/**
 * Returns customer Data with customer group only
 *
 * @return \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface
 */
protected function getDepersonalizedCustomer()
{
    $customer = $this->customerFactory->create();
    $customer->setGroupId($this->customerSession->getCustomerGroupId());
    return $customer;
}
```

So, this should work in a template

```
$customerGroupId = $this->helper('\Magento\Customer\Helper\Session\CurrentCustomer')->getCustomer()->getGroupId();
```

Comment: It will not work in template. Needs to extend \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper in order to use in template.