# Hide Price for a particular customer group

Tags: magento2, price, product-prices

How can i hide the price of products for a particular customer group?
I want to hide the price everywhere for this customer including checkout,cart pages.

Comment: please see this extension but u have to customize as per u r requirment https://marketplace.magento.com/estdevs-hideprice.html

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/172617/how-to-get-current-customer-group-id-in-magento2

Answer (score 0):

I had done it with plugin on same requirements,

Hide price box for specific customer group condition.

=> app/code/{{vendor}}/{{module}}/etc/di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox">
        <plugin name="price_hide" type="{{vendor}}\{{module}}\Plugin\HidePriceBox" sortOrder="1" disabled="false"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

=>app/code/{{vendor}}/{{module}}/Plugin/HidePriceBox.php

```
<?php
namespace {{vendor}}\{{module}}\Plugin;
class HidePriceBox
{
    protected $_customerSession;
    protected $_customerGroupCollection;

    public function __construct(        
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Group $customerGroupCollection
    ) {
        $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;    
        $this->_customerGroupCollection = $customerGroupCollection;
    }

    public function getCustomerGroup()
    {       
        $currentGroupId = $this->_customerSession->getCustomer()->getGroupId();
        $collection = $this->_customerGroupCollection->load($currentGroupId); 
        $customer_group = $collection->getCustomerGroupCode();
        return $customer_group;
    }

    function afterToHtml(\Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox $subject, $result)
    {
        $customerGroup = $this->getCustomerGroup();
        if($customerGroup == 'hide_customer_group')   //replace with customer group
        {
            return '';
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```