# Magento2.1.9 How to apply condition in checkout shipping method?

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods, customer-group

In magento2 checkout page i'm using free shipping method and i need to hide free shipping method only for non stocking customer group and rest of all customer group i want to display free shipping method.So anyone please guide me in which file i have to put condition.Please check attached image.[image]

Comment: can you please clarify non stocking customer group means?

Comment: Non stocking group menas => Not logged in users?

Comment: We have created in new customer group name called non stocking.

Comment: have you tried with cart price rules  ? https://prnt.sc/lk7xu9

Comment: Actually i don't want to apply free shipping i want to hide free shipping option in checkout page for particular customer  groups

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create custom module `Hello_World`
2. Create plugin and configure in `di.xml` file,  `app/code/Hello/World/di.xml`

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0"?>
>     <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd"> 
>         <type name="Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Freeshipping">
>           <plugin name="disable-freeshipping" type="Hello\World\Model\Carrier\Freeshipping" sortOrder="1" />  
>
>         </type>      
>  </config>
> ```

3. Create model file `app/code/Hello/World/Model/Carrier/Freeshipping.php`

   ```
   <?php

   namespace Hello\World\Model\Carrier;    

   class Freeshipping{

   protected $_checkoutSession;        

   protected $_scopeConfig;

   protected $_customerSession;

   public function __construct(
       \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
       \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
       \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
       \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
   ) {
       $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
       $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
       $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
       $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
   }

   public function afterCollectRates(\Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Freeshipping $freeshipping, $result)
   {   
       //Magento-2 Log Here
       $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP.'/var/log/magento2.log');
       $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
       $logger->addWriter($writer);
       //Customer Group ID Here
       $customerGroupId=$this->_customerSession->getCustomer()->getGroupId();     
       $logger->info("Free shipping has been calling and customerGroupId ".$customerGroupId);              
       //keep your customer group id here
       if($customerGroupId === '1'){
           return false;       
       }        
       return $result;
   }  

   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks In third steps what is file name  so we can override it

Comment: Please try this code in local instance first and test the scenarios and then confirm the same

Comment: but I think there are some naming issue in your above code "Create model file app/code/Hello/World/di.xml"

Comment: Yes @Saniya i have updated now please consider updated answer now

Comment: @Saniya  let me know whether this solution is working fine as you expected?

Comment: please accept my answer so that it will helpful to other developers who are looking for the solution as you faced scenario thanks

Comment: I need one more help please go this link "https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/250625/sql-error-while-adding-any-products-to-category-m2".if you have any idea reply me

Comment: please help me my above posted comment

Comment: Please go though my question i need help "https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/251728/checkout-page-order-summary-remove-shipping-method-for-non-logged-in-and-retail"

Answer (score 0):

For this, you need to create a custom shipping method.
The below link will helps you to create custom shipping method

https://webkul.com/blog/create-custom-shipping-method-in-magento2/

You can set the condition in the function collectRates in the file 
app/code/Webkul/Customshipping/Model/Carrier.php

Refer the below link to get customer group

[How to get current customer group id in magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/172617/how-to-get-current-customer-group-id-in-magento2)

Comment: Please go through this link "https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/250625/sql-error-while-adding-any-products-to-category-m2" if idea reply me

Comment: Sorry @Saniya i don't have any idea. but have you checked magento  2.1.14 default magento locally?

Comment: ok, let me check in my-side thanks for reply

Comment: @NagarajuKasa I need help please go thorough this link "https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/251650/magento2-category-custom-textarea-with-wysiwyg-editor-attribute-value-blank-iss"

Comment: @Saniya have you followed this https://inchoo.net/magento-2/add-category-attribute-magento-2/  ?

Comment: we have already follow that tutorial

Comment: let me try from my end get back to you @Saniya

Comment: In  order summary right side how to move  tax in magneto2

Comment: @Saniya i have answered for this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/251650/magento2-category-custom-textarea-with-wysiwyg-editor-attribute-value-blank-iss   . 2nd point is  regarding order summery if you posted question in stack can you please share the link

Comment: Please go through here 2point "https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/251949/magento2-tax-not-shows-for-not-logged-in-customer-issue"