# Not able to apply free shipping method when selecting custom customer group

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods, free-shipping, catalog-rules

I have created a new custom customer group, then i created a new cart rule to apply free shipping & assign that rule to new custom customer group. When i go to checkout page i am not getting Free shipping method.
Any suggestion will be appricated.
Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

Comment: hi @arjun did you assign the customer belongs to that newly created group?

Comment: have you checked that particular customer belongs to your newly created group or  not?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/250003/magento2-1-9-how-to-apply-condition-in-checkout-shipping-method/250536#250536 try with this in local instance

Comment: confirm, that rule working with magento default group?

Comment: Yes i have assign customer group + my customer belongs to newly created group + No i am facing same issue if i select retailer as my customer group

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine with the cart rule Please follow the below procedure as per given in the image below

1. Create a new customer group with name "free shipping"
2. Create a customer & assign that group to that customer.
3. create a cart rule follow the below given images

**cart rule:**

> 1) https://www.screencast.com/t/fWrzhWRtTq
>
> 2) https://www.screencast.com/t/aCsG8Kkal
>
> 3) https://www.screencast.com/t/a5eUQPs2nm

Now just login with that customer & try to place the order from the front-end it is working fine there

**please refer these images:**

Customer view & group: https://www.screencast.com/t/3b40M9b4ZK

checkout page: https://www.screencast.com/t/I5dycLzwGlr

> **Note:** Make sure you run the below commands after making the rules
>
> ```
> php bin/magento indexer:reindex
> php bin/magento cache:flush
> ```

Comment: i have verified you answer. I default magento2 i tried it is working fine. But in my case i have migrated data from m1 to m2. Could i  face this issue due to migrated data. As per my screenshot if i add amount above 300 then it is working fine. But i need above 0 for 1 specific group. I short i feel that my rule is not getting overridden by default config data stored in store -> Config

Comment: From my answer into this image -> https://www.screencast.com/t/aCsG8Kkal instead of placing 60 into the  condition section try to place 0 or 1& test I think It will work!