# Magento2 Tax not shows for Not logged in Customer issue

Tags: magento2, checkout, tax, order-summary

I'm using magento2. After add to cart product as guest customer tax not showing up on checkout page in Order Summary section but for registered customers tax showing up on checkout page. I have attached two images one for logged in customer and one for non-logged in customer. 
Notloggedin image here
[image]

Retail customer login after  image
[image]

cart page image
[image]

Any help should be appreciated here. Thanks.

Comment: have u checked any custom module effecting this?

Comment: Yes i have checked but i can't find out any solution why  guest customer  not show tax price here for two customer group not show shipping method in checkout page so i have using third party module for shipping there i  apply condition for shipping not display but my issue is tax not show in guest user

Comment: Generally tax applied on the basis of customer location, when user not registered (guest customer), then address is not available so it may be not being calculated. Please make sure if any conditions restricts guest users to applied tax (like tax applied to all customer groups etc etc.).

Comment: If i am checking estimate shipping section in cart page there tax shows "0" so whats issue please tell me

Comment: ok so what is other solution to resolve it

Comment: I would suggest to check if what customer groups the tax rule being applied to and make sure the guest users also allowed for that Customer Tax Class. I also need to check to help you in more better way, these are the basic idea what I am telling you..

Comment: i have add in my updated question one image for cart there not show tax

Comment: @NagarajuKasa how to add apply tax-rate  in my custom module  fee  display in order summary "Freight service"

Comment: let me check and update you @Saniya

Comment: @NagarajuKasa you get any solution for my tax rate not add to custom freight service like calculation is (cartsubtotal+freightservice->this total multiply by taxrate after display tax)

Comment: @NagarajuKasa have any get solution tax

Answer (score 1):

For the guest user, the tax will be calculated and shown in the checkout section after filling the shipping address form in the checkout page. Because Magento by default tax gets calculated based on the zipcode from the shipping address.

Answer (score 0):

You can set **Default tax destination calculation** here Stores >> Configuration >> Sales >> Tax

[image]