# Get website name from website id

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, multistore

I would like to add the magento website name to the top header beside the language switcher.

```
Magento_Store/templates/switch/languages.phtml
```

I can get the id by using,

```
echo $block->getCurrentWebsiteId();
```

How do I get the website name?

Answer (score 3):

In the current Magento 2.3.X versions (perhaps older as well), the above is definitely not a best practice. Instead, inject the interface `\Magento\Store\Api\WebsiteRepositoryInterface` as a dependency and call upon the repository as follows:

```php
$website = $this->websiteRepository->getById(42);
$website->getName();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public function __construct(

        \Magento\Store\Model\Website $websiteModel
    ..........
)
{
    $this->_websiteModel = $websiteModel;
}


public function getWebsiteName($websiteId)
    {
        $collection = $this->_websiteModel->load($websiteId,'website_id');
        return $collection->getName();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

in your block file, you can use below code :

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Store\Model\ResourceModel\Website\CollectionFactory $websiteCollectionFactory,
    ..........
)
{
    $this->_websiteCollectionFactory = $websiteCollectionFactory;
}

public function getWebsiteName()
{
    //$websiteId is your current website id
    $collection = $this->_websiteCollectionFactory->create()->load($websiteId,'website_id');
    $websiteData = $collection->getData();
    $websiteName = $websiteData[0]['name'];
    return $websiteName;
}
```

You can now call `getWebsiteName` in your phtml file to display the website name.

Comment: How would I override the block that the language switcher uses with that code?

Comment: @Manashvi i need help please go thorough this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/251949/magento2-tax-not-shows-for-not-logged-in-customer-issue?noredirect=1#comment355808_251949

Answer (score 0):

From your `phtml` you could get the current website name doing something like this:

```
$stores = $block->getStores();
foreach($stores as $store){
    if($store->getCode() == $block->getCurrentStoreCode()){
        $websiteName = $store->getWebsite()->getName();
    }
}
```

So you don't have to change the block.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function getWebsiteName($websiteId)
{  
   $collection = $this->_websiteCollectionFactory->create();
   $websiteData = $collection->addFieldToFilter('website_id',$websiteId);

   foreach($websiteData->getData() as $websiteName):
      $webName = $websiteName['name'];
   endforeach;

   return $webName;
}
```