# How to get Magento 2 customer group ID

Tags: magento2, customer, phtml, group, id

How to get Magento 2 customer group ID if user is logged in, in a .phtml file?
I have already tried with:

```
protected $_customerSession;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
) {
    $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
}

public function getGroupId(){
if($this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn()):
    echo $customerGroup=$this->_customerSession->getCustomer()->getGroupId();
endif;
}
```

but it doesn't work, I get this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'protected' (T_PROTECTED), expecting end of file in..
```

Comment: should try with https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/179253/33057

Comment: Check my answer: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/309909/59677

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the above code directly in your **phtml** file, Then it does not work.

To get logged in customer group id directly in **phtml** without using **Dependency Injection**,
You can use **object manager** to get group id in your **phtml** file.

```
<?php
  $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
  $customerSession = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
  if ($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
      echo 'Customer Group Id: ' .  $customerSession->getCustomer()->getGroupId();
  }
?>
```

**Using Dependency Injection**

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/CustomBlock.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block;
class CustomBlock extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $_customerSession;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\SessionFactory $customerSession,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_customerSession = $customerSession->create();
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getCustomerGroupId() {
        if ($this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
            return $this->_customerSession->getCustomerData()->getGroupId();
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now, you can use the functions in your **phtml** file as follows.

```
<?php echo 'Customer Group Id: ' . $block->getCustomerGroupId();  ?>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: That works great, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As you want Customer group id in phtml Then use **HTTP context  Variable** and  [View model.](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/view-models.html). using this two you can get **Customer group id for current logged in Customer**. Also, assume that You have using 2.2.X or 2.3.X version.

First, a take look On HTTP context  Variable https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/179253/4564

Create a View model Class to your module at`app/code/{VendorName}/{ModuleName}/ViewModel/CurrentCustomerGroup.php`.

*And here the code of this class*

```
<?php 
namespace {VendorName}\{ModuleName}\ViewModel;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Block\ArgumentInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Context as CustomerContext;

class CurrentCustomerGroup implements ArgumentInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context
     */
    private  $httpContext;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext

    ) {
        $this->httpContext = $httpContext;

    }
    public function getCustomerGroupCode()
    {
        if($this->httpContext->getValue(CustomerContext::CONTEXT_AUTH)){
            return $this->httpContext->getValue(CustomerContext::CONTEXT_GROUP);
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

**After that Class to your block class  using Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="{BlockNameinLayourFile}">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="view_model" xsi:type="object">{VendorName}\{ModuleName}\ViewModel\CurrentCustomerGroup</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Now, you can access `getCustomerGroupCode()` in your phtml using

```
<?php
$viewModel = $block->getViewModel();
?>
<?= $block->escapeHtml($viewModel->getCustomerGroupCode()); ?>
```

Comment: It's the correct way +1.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected $_customerSession;

protected $customerEntityFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerEntityFactory
) {
    $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
    $this->customerEntityFactory  = $customerEntityFactory;
}

public function getGroupId(){
    if($this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn()):
        $customerId = $this->_customerSession->getCustomerId();
        $customer = $this->customerEntityFactory->create()->load($customerId);
        echo $customerGroup = $customer->getGroupId();
    endif;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession using this class you will get current customer group id

```
protected $_customerSession;

public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
    ) {
        $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
    }

public function getGroupId() {
 if($this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
        echo $customerGroup = $this->_customerSession->getCustomer()->getGroupId();
   }
 }
```