# Magento2 user logged from php

Tags: magento2, php, login, user

In magento 2:
How can I see the user who is currently logged in from php? and 
How can I login to a user from code and save it in the database?

Comment: Possible duplication of https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91897/how-to-check-if-customer-is-logged-in-or-not-in-magento-2

Answer (score 0):

Magento provides info about the users currently online under customer section itself.

If you need to get the list of customers currently online you can make use of values from two magento database tables as per your need,

```
customer_vistor
customer_log
```

These table have a sessions of customers

You can login as a user by using a plugin https://github.com/magefan/module-login-as-customer