# Magento 2: Customer data from JS component

Tags: magento2, javascript, frontend, uicomponent

I need to get customer status in JS component - authenticated or anonymous. Could I get it using `Magento_Customer/js/customer-data` and how?

```
define([
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'
], function (customerData) {
    let isAnon = customerData.???
});
```

Comment: Check https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/203951/magento2-check-if-customer-is-logged-in-or-not-in-knockout-template .

Answer (score 3):

Yes, use `customerData.get(property)` where property is what you want to get. Example:

```
customerData.get('customer')
```

Comment: Does not work every time:
<code>
let customer = customerData.get('customer');
let firstName = customer().firstname;
let isLoggedIn = (typeof firstName != "undefined");
</code>
Sometimes `firstname` is undefined for logged in user.

Comment: What happens if you add `domReady!` as a dependency? Sounds like your script is loading too early.

Comment: with `domReady!` result the same - does not work all times. I use this <code>            let customer = window.customerData;
            let isLoggedIn = (typeof customer.id != "undefined");
</code> for now.

Comment: Hi @BenCrook, where can i get the list of properties which i can get from the customerData.get(??)

Comment: You could try logging it to see what data is available to you, I haven't tried this but it may work - `console.log(customerData.get('customer'))`