# How can i Check the user is log in or not?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.2.7

I have a html file not a .phtml file, i want to check custom is log in or not in html file, how can i do this?

Comment: An html file is not the place to check whether the customer is logged in or not

Comment: I want to hide one button in checkout page but the button code are store in html page, how can i hide that button if customer is not login @vitoriodachef

Comment: Refer the link for same 
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/203951/magento2-check-if-customer-is-logged-in-or-not-in-knockout-template?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a function in knockout and call this function to html file.

You need to pass dependency of customer object, `'Magento_Customer/js/model/customer'`

Your JS should be like this.

```
define(
[
    'ko',
    'jquery',   
    'Magento_Customer/js/model/customer',
    'mage/translate'
],
function (ko,jquery, customer,$t) {
    'use strict';
    return Component.extend({        
        isCustomerLoggedIn: customer.isLoggedIn, /*return  boolean true/false */
        initialize: function() {
            this._super();
            /* check using below method */
            var isLoggedIn = this.isCustomerLoggedIn();
        }
    });
}
```

And in your phtml file call function `data-bind="attr: { attr: isCustomerLoggedIn()}"`

Take reference from [magento2 check if customer is logged in or not in knockout template](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/203951/magento2-check-if-customer-is-logged-in-or-not-in-knockout-template?rq=1)

I hope it helps!

Comment: It gives me error  isCustomerLoggedIn is not a function

Comment: I have just shared logic `customer.isLoggedIn` using this you can get customer logged in or not, you have to create function.

Comment: okay thank you.