# How do I hide price from non-registered user in magento 2 for specific products

Tags: magento2, product, customer, price, login

I want to hide price from non registered users in magento 2 for specific products. I want to do this functionality by using any observer or plugins not from direct conditions in overwritten phtml files.

Answer (score 0):

First check if user is logged in or not

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
   // show price 
}else {
 // show some custom message or hide complete price logic
```

}

Must read : [How to check if customer is logged in or not in magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91897/how-to-check-if-customer-is-logged-in-or-not-in-magento-2/92133#92133)