# Magento 2 : Get Customer logged in details not Working on list.phtml

Tags: product-list, magento2.2.2, customer-session, logging

The code bellow isn't working on product listing page:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

  $customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');

echo   $customerSession->getCustomer()->getId()."<br/>";  // get 
  Customer Id
echo   $customerSession->getCustomer()->getName()."<br/>";  // get  
  Full Name
echo   $customerSession->getCustomer()->getEmail()."<br/>"; // get 
  Email Name
echo   $customerSession->getCustomer()->getGroupId()."<br/>";  // get 
 Customer Group Id
```

Source ref: [How to check if customer is logged in or not in magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91897/how-to-check-if-customer-is-logged-in-or-not-in-magento-2)
Any help! appreciated!

Comment: which value will be return?

Comment: check my code and let me know if you still face issue.

Comment: Using objectmanager is extremly dirty

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $customerSession = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');


if ($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
    $customerSession->getCustomerId();
    $customerSession->getCustomer();
    $customerSession->getCustomerData();

    echo $customerSession->getCustomer()->getName();  
    echo $customerSession->getCustomer()->getEmail();
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work! however I've found that using **SessionFactory** works! instead.

Answer (score 0):

Its working for me on list.phtml when create a new instance of object
$objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');