# Add CSS class to body if the customer is logged in magento 2

Tags: magento2, logging

i want to add css in top menu if the customer is logged in. I tried this code in `requirejs-config.js` :

```
var htmlBody = $("body[data-container='body']");
if ($(".customer-welcome").length) {
    htmlBody.addClass("customer-logged-in");
} else {
    htmlBody.addClass("customer-logged-out");
};
```

But no result so please can you help me to find a better solution and thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try my solution ?

Comment: Pawan thanks for your replay but i did not understand where to put this code and do i have to add 2 class in a css document and what's the meaning of "change the class name if the theme is not luma " ? please more explanation and really thanks a lot for your replay

Comment: Did you get a chance to see my recent comments ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid `$objectManager` directly, You can do it by JQuery

```
require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($){
  jQuery(document).ready( function() {
    var isLoggedIn = jQuery('.authorization-link > a').attr('href').indexOf('/login')<0;
        if(isLoggedIn){
            jQuery( ".body" ).addClass( "customer-welcome" );
        }
  });
});
```

IF `isLoggedIn` is `true`, it will add class to body.

**Note:** You may need to change class name, if it is not Luma Theme

Tested and Working. Hope above will Help!

Hint From [Answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91897/how-to-check-if-customer-is-logged-in-or-not-in-magento-2)  of [Comment](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/59735/sri)

Comment: can you please explain more where to put this code and do i have to create 2 class in css document and thanks for your replay

Comment: please answer me

Comment: please can you explain what do you mean by changing class name ???

Comment: Add above code to footer.phtml

Comment: Which theme you are using ?

Comment: shop4u is the name of theme that i am using

Comment: Have you tried my code in footer.phtml ? could you please share URL of website ?

Comment: no not yet :( can you please tell me the exactly module that i have to pout this code under (module_theme?) or i just have to create a new module and excuse me for my question because i still new in magento

Comment: This is  jquery code, you can put it any phtml or JS file. No need of additional module.

Comment: Even you can  test in console.

Comment: have you tried it again ?

Comment: Simply `alert(jQuery('.authorization-link > a').attr('href').indexOf('/login')<0);` in both case in console

Comment: I have checked for `shop4u` theme and it is working fine!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add to the different class to the body when the customer is logged out and logged in.

Create a custom module, which will add two custom layout handles, for example, `customer_logged_out` and `customer_logged_in` and add those handles to the layout.

Use the following code as the sample and modify it according to your requirement.

**app/code/Anshu/Custom/Observer/AddHandles.php**

```
<?php

namespace Anshu\Custom\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session as CustomerSession;

class AddHandles implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_customerSession;

    public function __construct(CustomerSession $_customerSession)
    {
        $this->_customerSession = $_customerSession;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $layout = $observer->getEvent()->getLayout();

        //To check that customer is logout
        if (!$this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn())
        {
            $layout->getUpdate()->addHandle('customer_logged_out');
        }
    }
}
```

**app/code/Anshu/Custom/view/frontend/layout/customer_logged_out.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <attribute name="class" value="my-class-test"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Above code is for the logged out customer, similarly, you can do it for logged in the customer as well.

Comment: This worked for me, but it left out one step which people may not know to do, which is to add the file `etc/events.xml` to your custom module and use it to call the AddHandles.php observer. `<event name="layout_load_before"><observer name="check_login_status" instance="[Custom]\[Module]\Observer\AddHandles" /></event>`

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but try this:

```
<?php 
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');

if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">',
  'jsfunction();',
  '</script>';
}
?>


<script type="text/javascript">
/// some code

    function jsfunction() {
        var htmlBody = $("body[data-container='body']");
        htmlBody.addClass("customer-logged-in");
    }

/// some code
</script>
```

I would not recommend using the object manager directly, use the dependency injection instead. The above is just an example...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php 
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');


<script>
$(document).onReady(){
  var isLoggedIn = "<?php echo $customerSession->isLoggedIn(); ?>";

  if(isLoggedIn == true){
    var htmlBody = $("body[data-container='body']");
    htmlBody.addClass("customer-logged-in");**strong text**
  }
}

</script>
```

Calls the function when the document is ready, and applies the defined class

also, backing up what bare feet said: you want to avoid using Object Manager where you can and should instead rely on dependency injection where you can. it would be better to define a block and call `isLoggedIn` from there, so +1 to him.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code in your phtml**

```
<?php
 $obm = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
 $context = $obm->get('Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context');
 $isLoggedIn = $context->getValue(\Magento\Customer\Model\Context::CONTEXT_AUTH);
 $customerIsLogging = 0;
?>

<?php if($isLoggedIn): ?>
    $customerIsLogging = 1;
<?php else: ?>
    $customerIsLogging = 0;
<?php endif; ?>


<script type="text/javascript">
    require(['jquery'], function($){
        var isLoggedIn = '<?php echo $customerIsLogging ?>';
        var htmlBody = $("body[data-container='body']");
        if(isLoggedIn == 1){
            htmlBody.addClass("customer-logged-in");
        }else{
            htmlBody.addClass("customer-logged-out");
        }
    });
</script>
```