# Add CSS class to menu if the customer is logged in magento 2

Tags: magento2, js-css

I asked a question about adding different class if customer is logged in or not logged : [Add CSS class to body if the customer is logged in magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/246309/add-css-class-to-body-if-the-customer-is-logged-in-magento-2) the problem is that i need more explanation to try the solution of pawan so can you please help me and thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

**Try this code in your phtml**

```
<?php
 $obm = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
 $context = $obm->get('Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context');
 $isLoggedIn = $context->getValue(\Magento\Customer\Model\Context::CONTEXT_AUTH);
 $customerIsLogging = 0;
?>

<?php if($isLoggedIn): ?>
    $customerIsLogging = 1;
<?php else: ?>
    $customerIsLogging = 0;
<?php endif; ?>


<script type="text/javascript">
    require(['jquery'], function($){
        var isLoggedIn = '<?php echo $customerIsLogging ?>';
        var htmlBody = $("body[data-container='body']");
        if(isLoggedIn == 1){
            htmlBody.addClass("customer-logged-in");
        }else{
            htmlBody.addClass("customer-logged-out");
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for your replay *any phtml ??

Comment: yes add header.phtml

Answer (score 0):

This is pawan's solution:

```
require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($){
    jQuery(document).ready( function() {
        var isLoggedIn = jQuery('.authorization-link > a').attr('href').indexOf('/login')<0;
        if(isLoggedIn){
            jQuery( ".body" ).addClass( "customer-welcome" );
        }
    });
});
```

Like above, he checked if the customer is logged in or not by using variable `isLoggedIn`.

`var isLoggedIn = jQuery('.authorization-link > a').attr('href').indexOf('/login')<0;`

So, he finds string `/login` from `<a href>` tag, if the customer logged in, the variable returns `true`, otherwise it returns `false`.

```
if(isLoggedIn){
     jQuery( ".body" ).addClass( "customer-welcome" );
}
```

And if it returns `true`, it will add the class to the `body`.

### Updated

You need to add this js to every pages in frontend like follow:

**1) Create js file `<vendor>/<module>/view/frontend/web/js/yourjs.js`**

```
define(['jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($){
    $(document).ready( function() {
        var isLoggedIn = $('.authorization-link > a').attr('href').indexOf('/login')<0;
        if(isLoggedIn){
            $(".body").addClass("customer-welcome");
        }
    });
});
```

**2) Declare `yourjs.js` with `requirejs-config.js` file**

Create `requirejs-config.js` file in `<vendor>/<module>/view/frontend`

with content below:

```
var config = {

// When load 'requirejs' always load the following files also
  deps: [
    "js/yourjs"
  ]
};
```

**3) Create default.xml in `<vendor>/<module>/view/frontend/layout`**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <script src="Vendor_Module::js/yourjs.js"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

Comment: so the class is added automatically i don't have to define a css class in css document ?? and where to put this code jquery ???

Comment: Yes you still need to define the style of the class, this code will just add class for body but not its style

Comment: and where to put this code please ??? *

Comment: and .addClass("customer-welcome" ) will be .addClass ("name of my css class ") ????

Comment: yes, it will be .addClass('your_class_name')

Comment: ok but where to put this jqyery code please

Comment: check my update above

Comment: thanks Draze this is very expalined just one question  this override have to be under my theme ?

Comment: when you trying to override magento core, you should do it by create a custom module, so yes, it should be under your custom module

Comment: This is not the good approach because as per the question, the class needs to be added if the customer is logged in. But according to the answer, there is no check for customer state rather you are adding the class based on the DOM element class. Suppose in future that DOM element is removed or class is changed then your code will not work.