# Login session does not work

Tags: magento2, login, session

I am trying to use login session on `magento/catalog/view/base/templates/product/price/amount/default.phtml`
to hide price from users not logged in.

However, it seems not working well with

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
    // customer login action
}
```

As well, I cannot find `\Magento\Framework\App` folder in my project. But, it seems working well tho. Is there any way that I can find this folder, and that makes it able to get login status?

Comment: You will find that folder in lib/internal/Magento or vendor/magento/framework.

Comment: Due to enabled full page cache you might not be getting correct data. Check different ways to achieve it which is mentioned in the thread https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/91897/9169