# How to get customer data from a table before logging in? magento2

Tags: magento2, event-observer, login

I need to check the status of the client (user data), if it is not active then ignore the login to the system

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite the customer LoginPost plugin

> Create a di.xml file **app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost">
        <plugin name="customer_login_plugin" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Customer\LoginPost" sortOrder="10" disabled="false"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

> Create a Plugin file **app/code/Vendor/Module/Plugin/Customer/LoginPost.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Customer;

class LoginPost
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
    ) {
        $this->_request = $context->getRequest();
        $this->_response = $context->getResponse();
    }

    public function aroundExecute(\Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost $subject, $proceed)
    {           
        $login =  $this->_request->getPost('login');     

        // before login check condition

        $returnValue = $proceed();            

        // after login check condition

        return $returnValue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This thread may help, you need to check if user is login or not. Than you can set your logic on basic of login(active) or not-logged  user.

[How to check if customer is logged in or not in magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91897/how-to-check-if-customer-is-logged-in-or-not-in-magento-2)