# How to get customer ID Magento 2.3.2

Tags: customer, customer-session, magento2.3.2, id

After logged in Magento frontend. I need to get ID of user on which account I am currently logged in.

Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if customer is logged in or not in magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91897/how-to-check-if-customer-is-logged-in-or-not-in-magento-2)

Answer (score 3):

> Try with changing the session object

```
 <?php
namespace YourCompanyName\YourModuleName\Block;
class YourCustomBlock extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $_customerSession;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\SessionFactory $customerSession,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_customerSession = $customerSession->create();
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getLoggedinCustomerId() {
        if ($this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
            return $this->_customerSession->getId();
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function getCustomerData() {
        if ($this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
            return $this->_customerSession->getCustomerData();
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now, we can use the functions in our view (.phtml) file as follows.

```
$customerId = $block->getLoggedinCustomerId();
echo 'Customer Id: ' . $customerId;

$customerData = $block->getCustomerData();
if($customerData) {
    echo 'Customer Id: ' . $customerData->getId() . '<br/>';
    echo 'Customer Name: ' . $customerData->getName() . '<br/>';
    echo 'Customer Email: ' . $customerData->getEmail() . '<br/>';
    echo 'Customer Group Id: ' . $customerData->getGroupId() . '<br/>';
}
```

> Try with objectmanger

```
$om = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerSession = $om->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
    $customerSession->getCustomer()->getId();
    $customerSession->getCustomer()->getName(); 
    $customerSession->getCustomer()->getEmail();
    $customerSession->getCustomer()->getGroupId(); // get Customer Group Id
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this below code in your block file :

```
protected $customerSession;

/**
 * Construct
 *
 * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
 * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
 * @param array $data
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
    array $data = []
) {
    parent::__construct($context, $data);

    $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
}

public function getCustomerId()
{
    $customerId = '';
    if($this->customerSession->isLoggedIn()){
        $customerId = $this->customerSession->getCustomer()->getId();
    }
    return $customerId;
}
```