# Magento 2 - How to check if an User is logged in?

Tags: magento2, customer, login

I want to check if a user is logged in.

Because I need to access customer-specific information.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if customer is logged in or not in magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91897/how-to-check-if-customer-is-logged-in-or-not-in-magento-2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by making this following Code in your .phtml file:

```
<?php
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $customerSession = $objectManager->create("Magento\Customer\Model\Session");
    $contractAddress = $block->getContractAddress();

    if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
        //Your Code
    }
  ?>
```

Comment: so I need this in my module's phtml file?

Comment: yes exactly, i hope i helped you fixing your problem

Comment: thanks a lot my friend.
very generous

Comment: So this is actually a bad answer?

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't know this

Comment: its not bad, but we should avoid to use object manager directly in our files.

Comment: No pave, the answer is correct but magento recommend don't use Model object directly and also don't use "ObjectManager" directly. So we should avoid it in any other case except "Customer Session"

Comment: @RahulAnand To what problems can this lead. i.e. security issues?

Comment: instead of obejct manager use a DI concept

public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
    ) {
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
    }

Comment: @pave, Calling a model object directly can raise error if all dependencies are not loaded which is needed by the model. DI concept says load API Interface and just because implementation of this interface is written in DI, it will load all the dependencies too without any fail.

Comment: Do I need a seperate file for the DI or can I use it in the .phtml?

Comment: I faced one error on checkout page "undefined call to a method getId() on null object" just because I was calling model directly. When I replaced it with "API Interface" that error went away because DI loaded all the dependencies.

Comment: There is no need to define your own di (etc/di.xml, etc/frontend/di.xml and etc/adminhtml/di.xml) unless you want to override a Model, Controller, Block OR if you want to define events, plugins and virtual types. 

You can use the __construct() DI method to initialize your API interface and call the methods to do some operations. Calling API method will call model's method as implementation is mentioned in di.xml files for all modules.

Comment: @pave you need to define this in di.xml file and in __construct methods in your php files. you can't do this in phtml files without $objectManager, which is not a recommended approach.

Comment: ok I think I understand now. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Cheers !! Happy to help

Answer (score 4):

You can check this with

```
class MyClass
{
    protected $customerSession;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession) {
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
    }

    public isCustomerLoggedIn() {
        return $this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn();
    }
}
```

Comment: where do I need to place this.
I have no clue about magento

Comment: I think in your Block .php file

Comment: You can implement in Helper/Data.php or in Block class.

Comment: It needs to be written in php file. Write it in your controller, Block, Helper files.

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

```
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;

/**
 * Class Index
 */
class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

/**
 * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context
 * @param Customer
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    Session $customerSession,
) {
    $this->customerSession   = $customerSession;
    parent::__construct($context);
}
public function execute()
{
            if ($this->customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
                $this->messageManager->addWarning('User is loggedIn');
                return $resultRedirect;
            }
        } else {
            $this->messageManager->addWarning('User Not loggedIn');
            return $resultRedirect;
        }
     }

}
```