# Magento 2 - Cache problem for check if user is logged in phtml file

Tags: magento2, blocks, cache

I use this code, on `.phtml` file,

```
if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {}
```

for check if the user is logged. But, when I active the cache, this code does not work fine.
How I can resolve this problem?

Comment: you can refer this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91897/how-to-check-if-customer-is-logged-in-or-not-in-magento-2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if customer is logged in or not in magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91897/how-to-check-if-customer-is-logged-in-or-not-in-magento-2)

Comment: are you calling `block` for phtml file from .xml file?

Answer (score 0):

Utilising knockout is another approach

```
<div class="greet welcome" data-bind="scope: 'customer'">
    <!-- ko if: customer().is_logged_in  -->
    <span class="logged-in"
            data-bind="text: new String('<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Welcome back %1', '%1')) ?>').replace('%1', customer().firstname)">
    </span>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko ifnot: customer().is_logged_in  -->
    <span class="not-logged-in"
            data-bind='html:"<?= $block->escapeHtml(__("Please <a href='%1'>login</a>", $block->getUrl('customer/account/login'))) ?>"'>
    </span>
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

https://github.com/DominicWatts/CustomerLogin