# How get user information inside of controller

Tags: magento2, controllers

I create route, and controller for it.
All works fine if i call route like so.

....

```
return $this->_pageFactory->create();
```

....

However when I want get user data from `Magento\Customer\Model\Session` inside controller i get error. I use $om to get data but i don`t know why it crash. I need user session for redirect to login form if user is not logged in.

```
...
        $om = $context->getObjectManager();
        $this->_customerSession = $om->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
        $this->_resultFactory = $context->getResultFactory();
...
```

in execute

```
if ($this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
    return $this->_pageFactory->create();
}
$redirect = $this->_resultFactory->create(\Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
$redirect->setUrl('/customer/account/create/');
return $redirect;
```

So question is how to redirect customer away from route if its not log in ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if customer is logged in or not?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91897/how-to-check-if-customer-is-logged-in-or-not)

Comment: Replace with $redirect->setUrl('customer/account/create/');

Comment: redirect works i just don`t want to use objectManager in controller to create dependency. But when i add dependency to constructor it breaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use like below in your controller to get customer session.

```
<?php
/**
 *
 * Copyright © 2015 Zmagecommerce. All rights reserved.
 */
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Index;

class Custom extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action 
{
    protected $_customerSession;
    
    protected $_customerUrl;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Url $customerUrl
    ) {
        $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->_customerUrl = $customerUrl;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function isCustomerLogin()
    {
        return $this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn();
    }

    public function getCustomerLoginUrl() 
    {   
        return $this->_customerUrl->getLoginUrl();
    }
}
```